# negative values ​of \topsep in the list environment

Tags: spacing

Why do the negative values ​​of \ topsep only affect the bottom of the list and not the top?

To what is due? Does anyone know?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.15}

\newenvironment{milista}{\begin{list}{$\bullet$}{%
                    \setlength\topsep{-10 pt}%
                    \setlength\partopsep{0 pt}%
                    \setlength}}%
                    {\end{list}}
                                  


\begin{document}

    Vamos a introducir algunos resultados relevantes en torno al análisis matemático que utilizaremos
    posteriormente: 
        
        \begin{milista}
            \item Si $f$ es una función continua en $[a,b]$ tal que $f(a)\,f(b)<0$, entonces existe
            $c\in (a,b)$ de forma que $f(c)=0$.
            
            \item Si $f$ es una función continua en $[a,b]$, y derivable en $(a,b)$, con $f(a)=f(b)$, 
            entonces existe
            $c\in (a,b)$ de forma que $f'(c)=0$.
            
            \item El teorema de Lagrange afirma que...
        \end{milista}           


    Como se puede observar, si $p(x)=0$ es una ecuación polinómica, y deseamos encontrar las soluciones
    de dicha ecuación en $[a,b]$, entonces podemos echar mano de los resultados anteriores para garantizar
    la existencia, o para demostrar la inexistencia de las mismas.
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Setting `\topset` have influence on the top and bottom of list. See for example documentation for `\enumitem` package, page 3. If you like to reduce vertical space above/below list, set for example `\topsep` to zero. For defining new list I suggest to use `enumitem` package.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511018/, it may help you.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in my comment, parameter `topsep` influence on the vertical distances at top and bottom of lists. See illustration form documentation for `enumitem` package, page 3:

[image]

I guessing that you like to reduce spaces between list and surrounding text as well between items in list. This is simple to achieve with use of the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{milista}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list
\setlist[milista]{nosep=0pt,     % <-- new list setup
                  label=$\bullet$ ,
                  }
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.15}

\begin{document}
Vamos a introducir algunos resultados relevantes en torno al análisis matemático que utilizaremos
posteriormente:

    \begin{milista}
        \item Si $f$ es una función continua en $[a,b]$ tal que $f(a)\,f(b)<0$, entonces existe
        $c\in (a,b)$ de forma que $f(c)=0$.

        \item Si $f$ es una función continua en $[a,b]$, y derivable en $(a,b)$, con $f(a)=f(b)$,
        entonces existe
        $c\in (a,b)$ de forma que $f'(c)=0$.

        \item El teorema de Lagrange afirma que...
    \end{milista}

Como se puede observar, si $p(x)=0$ es una ecuación polinómica, y deseamos encontrar las soluciones
de dicha ecuación en $[a,b]$, entonces podemos echar mano de los resultados anteriores para garantizar
la existencia, o para demostrar la inexistencia de las mismas.
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case, that you like only to reduce space between lists and items, then try for example the following list setting:

```
\setlist[milista]{topsep=0.5ex,     % <-- new list setup
                  parsep=0.5ex,
                  label=$\bullet$ ,
                  }
```

which used in above MWE (Minimal Working Example) give:

[image]

For more options, see documentation for `enumitem`package, which is part of your LaTeX installation or you can find at
[CTAN: enumitem](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=en).

**Edit:** Design of lists anticipated that user will not use negative vertical distances (`\topsep`, `\parskip`, `partopsep` and `\itemsep`). In a cases that you anyway use for example `\topsep` as you try in your document example it will happen as you observe: negative residues of your settings are accumulated at end of list.

*Conclusion:* don't use negative values for vertical distances in definitions of new lists. Use anticipated values (zero or positive) in defining of own lists. What you try is wrong approach.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But why does a negative length of \ topsep only affect the space after the text? Observe in the image how only the subsequent text (which rises vertically) is altered.

Comment: @GermánGarcíaLópez, see the figure explaining the meaning of list's parameters. It change both distance, on the top and at the bottom. It is not clear, what you like to obtain, however your approach (using negative values for distances) is wrong. In answer I show you possible correct solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply once again. He was simply trying to understand the reason for that behavior. On some occasions I have used negative distances when I change \parskip, since, in these cases, the top distance of a list is greater than the subsequent distance. So in these cases I do use \setlength\topsep {-\parskip}.

However, in this case, I know that there is no point in using negative distances, but playing with the values, I don't understand why it does affect the lower spacing, but not the upper one.

Comment: @GermánGarcíaLópez, see edit in ma answer.

Comment: Thank you very much again. But, if I put \renewcommand\baselinestretch {1.15} and
\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}, how do I reduce the top and bottom space a bit so there is not so much space? The top and bottom space is \topsep + \parskip [+ \partopsep]. So if I put \setlength \topsep{0pt}, the space corresponding to \parskip will remain. Thanks for your answers. They are helping me a lot.